# NodeJS помогите с запросом и получением данных (fetch)

Tags: json, сервер, fetch

```
fetch('http://localhost:80/read', {
  method: 'post',
  mode: 'no-cors',
})
  .then(function(response) { 
    console.log(response.json());
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

server.js

```
app.post('/read', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('./test.json', 'utf-8', (err, jsonString) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(jsonString); //Все выводит как надо
      res.json(jsonString);
    }
  });
});
```

Я получаю ошибку

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/read', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('./test.json', 'utf-8', (err, jsonString) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(jsonString);
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            res.write(jsonString);
            res.end();
        }
    });
});
```